# Procedure MySQL cursor taking a long time to execute

Tags: mysql, optimization, stored-procedures, mysql-5.7, cursors

I have a MySQL procedure, with a cursor in it. The sample cursor query is given below

```
DECLARE cs CURSOR FOR
           (SELECT  a.mag_id FROM A a  WHERE
                a.creation_date BETWEEN (v_fromdate) AND (v_todate) 
                AND a.type_id IN (SELECT type_id FROM key2 WHERE   sessionId=v_sessionId)
                AND a.mag_id IN (SELECT magid FROM    key1 WHERE   sessionId=v_sessionId order by magid)
                )
     UNION
                (SELECT  b.combo_mag_id FROM B b 
                WHERE
                b.creation_date BETWEEN (v_fromdate) AND (v_todate) 
                AND b.type_id IN (SELECT type_id FROM    key2 WHERE   sessionId=v_sessionId)
                AND b.combo_mag_id IN (SELECT magid FROM    key1 WHERE   sessionId=v_sessionId order by magid)
                );

DECLARE
CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
SET v_cur_time = now();
SET v_cur_query = 'cursor';
OPEN cs;
SELECT timestampdiff(SECOND,v_cur_time,now()) into v_diff;
SELECT CONCAT('Current Query: ', v_cur_query, ' Time taken: ', v_diff);
```

Both table A and B have millions of records.I have partitions created in both the tables with partition by range on creation_date.For 3 months of a date range the cursor takes almost 4 mins to execute.But when i tried running the same query in  MySQL workbench editor,by setting the parameters for the same date range it took only 22 seconds. Can somebody tell me why it executes faster in an SQL editor, and since i have to use it in the stored procedure, is there any way to optimize it ??

Answer (score 0):

- `IN ( SELECT ... )` is often poorly optimized.  See if you can turn it into either a `JOIN` or `EXISTS ( SELECT 1 ... )`
- Don't use a `CURSOR` if it is possible to write a `JOIN` or something to do the entire task rather than acting one row at a time.
- `PARTITIONing` is unlikely to be beneficial; let's see the details.  (Composite indexes often do the job adequately.)
- Remove the `ORDER BY` in subqueries; it has no effect.  If you need ordering, please elaborate; we should be able to find another way.
- Are there parameters being fed in?  Which?

Comment: yes ,  v_fromdate and v_todate are the parameters in the between clause for creation_date and session_id is another parameter. Can we use any datetime index for a between clause in query?? in my case it will be for creation_date. And if yes, the  how to get an index_range scan out of it ??

Comment: @PrasenjitDebnath - perhaps I need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the rest of the Procedure declaration.